Efficient Clifford simulation and entropy of reduced density matrices
Suppose I have a Clifford circuit $C$ and I want to estimate the entanglement entropy of a subset of two qubits, say, $\{q_0, q_1\}$, i.e. the quantity $$S(\rho_{q_0 q_1}) = - \text{Tr}[\rho_{q_0 q_1} \log (\rho_{q_0 q_1})]$$
where $\rho_{q_0 q_1}$ is the reduced density matrix obtained (for example) by tracing out $C |0\rangle \langle 0| C^\dagger$ over all qubits except $q_0, q_1$. My question is: is it possible to efficiently calculate this quantity, either analytically or empirically?
Of course, one can't just apply the approach of calculating $C |0\rangle \langle 0| C^\dagger$, since this is a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix and thus cannot be represented efficiently.

TL;DR: Yes, we can efficiently compute von Neumann entropy $S(\rho)$ of a $k$-qubit mixed state $\rho$ obtained by tracing out $n-k$ qubits from a pure $n$-qubit stabilizer state $|\psi\rangle$ using
\begin{align}
S(\rho)=k-m\tag1
\end{align}
where $m$ is the number of independent generators of the subgroup of the stabilizer group of $|\psi\rangle$ consisting of operators that act as identity on the traced out qubits.

Consider a set $A$ of $k$ qubits and a set $B$ of $n-k$ qubits whose joint quantum state is the pure stabilizer state $|\psi\rangle$ with stabilizer group $\mathcal{S}$ generated by $n$ independent generators in $\mathcal{G}$. It's easy to check that
\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\prod_{g\in\mathcal{G}}\frac{I+g}{2}=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}}s.\tag2
\end{align}
Let $\rho:=\mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)$ denote the reduced state of the $k$ qubits in $A$. Consider the set $\mathcal{S}_A\subset\mathcal{S}$ of $n$-qubit Pauli operators that act as identity on $B$. Clearly, $\mathcal{S}_A$ is an abelian subgroup of the $n$-qubit Pauli group. Therefore, $|\mathcal{S}_A|=2^m$ where $m\in\{0,\dots,k\}$ is the number of independent generators of $\mathcal{S}_A$.
Now, define $P:=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}_A|}\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}_A}s$. Again, since $\mathcal{S}_A$ is a group, we find that $sP=P$ for every $s\in\mathcal{S}_A$. Consequently, $P^2=P$, so $P$ is a projector. On the other hand, we have
\begin{align}
\rho=\mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}}\mathrm{tr}_B(s)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}_A}\mathrm{tr}_B(s)\tag3
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\rho\otimes I_B=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}_A}\mathrm{tr}_B(s)\otimes I_B=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}_A}s=\frac{|\mathcal{S}_A|}{2^k}P=\frac{1}{2^{k-m}}P\tag4
\end{align}
so $\mathcal{\rho}$ has a flat spectrum with eigenvalues in $\{0,2^{m-k}\}$. Therefore, von Neumann entropy of $\rho$ is
\begin{align}
S(\rho)=k-m.\tag5
\end{align}
If you have a tableau representation of the original stabilizer group $\mathcal{S}$, then you can efficiently find $m$, and hence $S(\rho)$, using techniques from Gaussian elimination.
